# Spotfire: add column with values based on marking in another table

Tags: scripting, spotfire

In Spotfire I have two tables "A" and "B" with a shared column "id". Let x be the set of "id" values of the marked rows in A. I would like to add a new column "flag" to B such that:

- flag = 1 if B.id is in x
- flag = 0 otherwise

Can somebody help me put together a script (IronPython, I guess), to achieve this? Here's an example (the columns a, b, c and x, y, z don't matter):

```
   A: id a b c
      1*  
      2 
      2*
      3
      3
```

(* indicate marked rows)

```
   B: id x y z
       1
       1
       2
       2
       2
       3
       3
```

should result in:

```
   B: id x y z flag
       1       1 
       1       1 
       2       1
       2       1
       2       1
       3       0
       3       0
```

Comment: if you are okay with keeping the flag inside of the DXP, you can look into the "tagging" feature. I don't know enough about it to explain it well, but essentially you assign rows to different tags, which creates a metadata column containing your flag value. you can automate this with python, too.

Comment: i'm okay with keeping the flag inside the DXP. Creating the flag column should be completely automated, though.

Comment: I’m not hopeful the capability is there, but there may be a creative way to join and insert within Spotfire. I’ll take another look on Monday but maybe someone will have a better response before that!

Answer (score 3):

I found a solution thanks to niko's comment and the following example scripts:

- https://community.tibco.com/wiki/how-retrieve-data-marking-selection-using-ironpython-tibco-spotfire
- http://spotfired.blogspot.com/2014/02/mark-selected-row.html
- https://community.tibco.com/wiki/how-tag-marked-rows-using-tibco-spotfire-using-ironpython-scripting

Here's the idea:

1. collect the set x of marked 'id' values in A
2. using a second marking, mark rows in B where 'id' value is in x
3. assign tag "0" to all rows in B, then assign tag "1" to only the marked rows in B

I manually created the 'flag' column with the "0" and "1" tags. I'm not sure whether this could be automated, too.

Here's the complete script:

```
sourceTableName           = 'A'
sourceMarkingName         = 'Marking'
sourceTableIDColumnName   = 'id'

targetTableName           = 'B'
targetMarkingName         = 'Marking (2)'
targetTableIDColumnName   = 'id'
targetTableFlagColumnName = "flag"


from System.Collections.Generic import List
from Spotfire.Dxp.Data import *


dataManager   = Application.Document.Data
sourceTable   = Document.Data.Tables[sourceTableName]
sourceMarking = dataManager.Markings[sourceMarkingName]
targetTable   = Document.Data.Tables[targetTableName]
targetMarking = dataManager.Markings[targetMarkingName]


#:::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
#
# step 1: get set of id values marked in source table
#
#:::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::

# Create a cursor for the table column to get the values from
sourceCursor = DataValueCursor.CreateFormatted(sourceTable.Columns[sourceTableIDColumnName])

# Create a List object to store the values for the rows marked in the source table
markedData = List[str]();

# Iterate through the source data table rows to retrieve the marked values
for row in sourceTable.GetRows(sourceMarking.GetSelection(sourceTable).AsIndexSet(), sourceCursor):
    value = sourceCursor.CurrentValue
    if value <> str.Empty:
        markedData.Add(value)

# Get the unique values
idValues = sorted(List[str](set(markedData)))


#:::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
#
# step 2: use the id values to mark rows in target table
#
#:::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::

# Set marking of all rows in target table to False
rowsToSelect = IndexSet(targetTable.RowCount, False)

targetCursor = DataValueCursor.CreateFormatted(targetTable.Columns[targetTableIDColumnName])

# Iterate through the target table rows to set the marked rows
rowIndex = 0
for row in targetTable.GetRows(targetCursor):
    value = targetCursor.CurrentValue
    rowsToSelect[rowIndex] = value in idValues
    rowIndex += 1

# Set marking on targetTable
targetMarking.SetSelection(RowSelection(rowsToSelect), targetTable)

#:::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
#
# step 3: assign tag '1' to the marked rows and '0' to all other rows in the target table
#
#:::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::

# Get handle to the required column and typecast it to a tagcolumn
myTagColumn = targetTable.Columns.Item[targetTableFlagColumnName].As[TagsColumn]()

# get index to all rows
allRows = IndexSet(targetTable.RowCount, True)

# assign tags
myTagColumn.Tag('0', RowSelection(allRows))                     # assign '0' to all rows
myTagColumn.Tag('1', targetMarking.GetSelection(targetTable))   # assign '1' to marked rows
```